# Is value purely based on preference?

Tags: values

To me, value seems like just an arbitrary concept we attach to things based off of how positively or negatively they currently/eventually will effect us. Since whether or not things can be positive or negative is based on preference, is value also preference based? Does this mean that nothing can have an underlying constant value?

Comment: If it is based on how things will affect us how is it arbitrary? It is not like we can *choose* in most cases if we are affected, or whether it is positively or negatively. Moreover, there often tends to be consensus on which way the effect goes, say with lying, theft or murder. If this is "arbitrary" then so is weight or temperature.

Comment: Do you prefer water or thirst? Food or hunger... Etc.  There's an absolute value.

Comment: And even if values are subjective, they can still be _wrong_, by nature of being internally inconsistent... valuing A more than B, and B more than C, but valuing C more than A.  Or wrong by non-conformance to reality.

Comment: "Price is what you pay. Value is what you get." -- Warren Buffet.

Comment: A correlated question: If 100% of people agree on whether something is positive, does that mean it is objectively positive?  Or does it merely mean that subjects are in agreement about a subjective positivity?

Comment: @Richard I think that arguing for the absolute value there requires us to remove the subjective phrasing.  "Is it preferable for Richard to have water, or for Richard to be thirsty."  In that case, it it is hypothetically possible for me to hate you enough to prefer you to be thirsty.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm pretty sure everyone values water. Their desire or otherwise to withhold it from others demonstrates it's absolute value.. I would argue.

Comment: @Richard I think some of that argument stems from imprecision.  "Values water" is a tremendously ambiguous phrase.  That being said, I am quite certain that an individual from Tennessee, where it rains constantly, values water remarkably differently than an individual from Arizona does.  And  presumably a man who is drowning has a very different value statement for water indeed.

Comment: @CortAmmon no.. I'm pretty sure that everyone values drinking water for the purposes of not dying of thirst.. absolutely.. conversely I'm sure nobody enjoys drowning. Absolute things exist.. including absolute truth... Sophism.. is sophism.

Comment: @Richard Are you interested in picking a single value statement to discuss?  Are we discussing "My value of me not dying of thirst?"  That would be more precise (and also not absolute, because there are people who have been force fed water, or even IV drips, because they would prefer dying of thirst over their environment)

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm interested in the concept of absolute value.. what you are doing is called 'equivocating'... Which is a technique taught by the sophists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87160/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-richard).

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that he strongest form of your prostitution would be: The Law and general moral code of society is constituted and developed by the transient preference (and prejudice) of the people. It should be evident that while there are certainly examples from history to support your standpoint, contemporary society display obvious signs of other influences.

One such influence may be found in the field of Ethics, or moral philosophy.
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics
  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/morality-definition/

Exploring this field should show how particular philosophers have influenced the politics of the time as well as how philosophical schools have at different times steered public opinion and practices of the legal establishment.

*Note, your concern could return in another form if stated thus: The philosophy and ethics of the time are shaped by the will and whims of the people.*

Answer (score 1):

Georg Simmel's *The Philosophy of Money* is one of the most thorough developments of a theory of value that I'm aware of. This quote from the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Philosophy_of_Money) about the book may be helpful:

> Simmel believed people created value by making objects,
>   separating themselves from those objects and then trying to overcome
>   that distance. He found that objects that were too close were not
>   considered valuable and objects that were too far away for people to
>   obtain were also not considered valuable. What was also considered in
>   determining value was the scarcity, time, sacrifice, and difficulties
>   involved in getting objects. In the pre-modern era, beginning with
>   bartering, different systems of exchange for goods and services
>   allowed for the existence of incomparable systems of value (land,
>   food, honor, love, etc.). With the advent of a universal currency as
>   an intermediary, these systems became reconcilable, as everything
>   tended to become expressible in a single quantifiable metric: its
>   monetary cost.

One problem with the OPs query concerns use of the word *preference*. It is not a unidimensional concept as *preference* has many meanings and usages in fields as diverse as probabilistic choice theory, economics, marketing, philosophy, psychology and more. Richard Thaler, the Nobel Laureate and behavioral economist, describes a human process of *mental accounting* in which preferences are formed, embedded and used in making decisions. While a useful metaphor, the actual mechanisms of this process of mental accounting are fairly opaque. Add to that the complication that people often falsify their preferences in order to conform with social norms.

Answer (score 0):

Some writers (only Stephen Covey comes to my mind) oppose values and principles. Both are intended to improve the survival of the group.

Values are completely subjective and principles can be considered as objective, common to all. Values are assigned by societies (jewelry, having long ears money, a big big big car, etc.) and they are relative. On the other hand, principles, like loyalty, honesty, fidelity, etc. can be assessed as objectively positive.

Principles, clearly, help improving the group interactions, and might be understood as positive, because they are assessed based on past knowledge. Values are usually more superficial, and can be effectively bad for the group even if the group considers them good.

The line between both of them is hard to assess. Remember that any group makes its best shot to persist, but not all succeed. That means that values assessed as positive can effectively be destructive.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, "value" is purely subjective - excluding clean water and edible food (survival necessities). Once a community, or individual, transcends these basic needs then everything else seen as "valuable" is solely tied to comfort or personal interests (greed).

Comment: Would you have references to people who share this view so readers can get more information? This would also strengthen your answer. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: There are people who go on hunger strikes.  For them, for the duration of their strike, food has zero value.  Sometimes, when I've drunk a lot of water, I don't want any more for a while.  People don't have to consistently value survival necessities.